# How do I replace non-numeric characters in string while excluding periods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, web

So I have this-

```
lr_min = $('#lr_min').val().replace(/\D/g,'');
```

It gets rid of all the nonnumeric characters in the string. How do I exclude periods (.) from this replace?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
lr_min = $('#lr_min').val().replace(/[^\d.]+/g,'');
```

The `+` isn't strictly necessary but will usually give [better performances](http://jsperf.com/replace-reg) (less replacements)

Answer (score 0):

You could Ignore the dots between the numbers.

`lr_min = $('#lr_min').val().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');`

Comment: In case the number is negative it will keep the '-' sign so if for example '$ -100.50' it the result will be '-100.50'

Comment: Not really what was being asked for, though.